# Include pdf pages in a latex document as appendix

Tags: publishing

I am writing a report and would like to include as appendix another document which is in pdf format.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [pdfpages](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package to include the relevant pages.

Comment: Just for those who don't want to look up the documentation: Use `\includepdf{file}`.

Comment: An updated link to the package: http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages

Comment: @JonO. Thanks for spotting that: I've updated

Comment: Do you know if this package is available as basic package within MikTeX?

Comment: @Sigur `pdfpages` is available in both TeX Live and MiKTeX ...

Comment: In a basic installation as well? I am going to load it on a package I am writing but I'd like to be sure that people would have no problem with it.